# Habilitar boton cuando la table html este vacia

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde elimino filas de una tabla, al momento que la tabla este vacia quiero habilitar el boton Agregar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "Agregar Nueva Linea",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                addNewLine();
            }
        })

    });

    function addNewLine() {
        $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function() {
            var tbody = $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody");

            if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
                alert('1');
                $("#btn_save_line").attr("disabled", false);
                return;
            }

        });
    }

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>


       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_line" disabled="disabled" >Agregar</button>
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span>  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 2</td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span> </td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el codigo tienes que siempre y cuando el `tbody`  tenga elementos `tr`, es cuando el metodo `.each()` se ejecuta:

```
 $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function() { //...
```

Por lo que cuando ya no le quedan elementos, el metodo `.each()` no sera ejecutado.

Intenta verificar si la tabla le queda algun `tr` sin utilizar el .`each()`:

```
function addNewLine() {
  if ($("#tbl_cotizacion tbody tr").length === 0) {
     alert('1');
     $("#btn_save_line").attr("disabled", true);
     return;
   }
}
```

Codigo que se puede hacer mas corto:

```
function addNewLine() {
   $("#btn_save_line").attr("disabled", $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody tr").length === 0);
}
```

Aqui el codigo completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "Agregar Nueva Linea",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                addNewLine();
            }
        })

    });

    function addNewLine() {
    
      if ($("#tbl_cotizacion tbody tr").length === 0) {
        alert('1');
        $("#btn_save_line").attr("disabled", true);
        return;
       }
    }

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>


       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_line" disabled="disabled">Agregar</button>
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span>  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 2</td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span> </td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: thanks my budda muy bien explicado

Answer (score 2):

Saludos puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Esta seguro?',
            text: "Desea eliminar la fila?",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Si',
            cancelButtonText:'No'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                var totalFilas = $('tbody tr').length;
               if(totalFilas == 0){
               document.getElementById("btn_save_line").disabled = false; 
               }
            }
        })

    });

    function addNewLine() {
     alert('agregar fila');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>


       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_line" disabled="disabled" >Agregar</button>
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span>  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 2</td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up arriba'></span>  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down abajo'> </span> </td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Si te fijas he agregado una validacion en donde eliminas las filas:

```
   var totalFilas = $('tbody tr').length;
    if(totalFilas == 0){
       document.getElementById("btn_save_line").disabled = false; 
   }
```

Tan solo cuento los elementos existentes del tbody con jquery y si es igual a cero habilito el boton de agregar con:

```
 document.getElementById("btn_save_line").disabled = false;
```

para inactivar el boton seria:

```
document.getElementById("btn_save_line").disabled = true;
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!